# How to create custom security namespace in Azure DevOps extension

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

According to the official wiki of Azure DevOps REST API, we have abilities to check Permissions for users using security namespaces.

We have an endpoint to check permissions:
[Permissions - Has Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/permissions/has-permissions?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#a-list-of-tokens)

And we have the list of predefined namespaces:
[Security Namespaces - Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/security-namespaces/security-namespaces-query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

**Is it possible to add your own security namespaces?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add your own security namespaces?

I am afraid that there is no such method  could create own security namespaces.

The security namespace in the organization is fixed and cannot be changed.

Therefore, it is not possible to add custom security namespaces.

For more detailed about the security namespaces, you can refer to this doc: [Security namespace and permission reference for Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/namespace-reference?view=azure-devops)

This doc lists all security namespaces lists.